# Is there a way to dynamically change the Flutter TextField's maxLines?

Tags: textarea, textfield, flutter

I have a TextField like this:

```
new Flexible(
    fit: FlexFit.loose,
    child: new Container(
        alignment: FractionalOffset.topLeft,
        child: new TextField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Add a note',
            ),
            maxLines: 1,
            onChanged: (value) => _showSaveOptions(value),
        ),
    ),
),
```

I'd like to have my TextField to start out with `maxLines` set to 1, but as I type, I would like the maxLines to increase, so that all the text remains on the page and I don't have to scroll up. However, I also don't want to start off with `maxLines` set to say, 5 or 10, because the empty TextField takes up more space that necessary. An example of the behavior I want to implement is in the Long Answer Text option in Google Forms, where it starts with one line:
[image]
and expands as I type:
[image]

I've considered setting `maxLines` to a counter that increments every time the user hits a newline, but how do I determine when the user has filled up a line?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Flutter was lagging multiline support in TextField. After an [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8028) was raised regarding the same, the multiline feature has been added in the [0.0.16](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/releases/tag/0.0.16) release.

Make sure you upgrade flutter to the latest release. To get multiline TextField use:

```
new TextField(
    maxLines: null,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
)
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: This is great, thanks! Turns out I can't set maxLines to null right now due to this [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12046), but I expect this to work once it is resolved.

Comment: this only looks like a text filed. not look like textarea.

Answer (score 4):

its look like a text-area. you can try with **maxLines**

> maxLines: 8

```
TextField(
        maxLines: 8,
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter your text here", border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Post Body'),
    ),
```