# Get multi-line Text in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

[image: Demo]

How can I achieve the multi-Line view on Text and Multi-Line TextField that can auto size the container at the bottom.

Edit:And align them properly

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have this in the following question:
[Is there a way to dynamically change the Flutter TextField's maxLines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760946/is-there-a-way-to-dynamically-change-the-flutter-textfields-maxlines)

Set this on your code:

```
new TextField(
      maxLines: null,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
);
```