# How to make Flutter TextField accept multiline?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make Flutter `TextField` accept multiline? The following code does NOT work:

```
body: Padding(
    child: Column(
        children: [
            Text('BIO'),
            Expanded(
                child: TextField(
                    autofocus: false,
                    controller: _text,
                    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/46767771
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                    maxLength: null,
                ),
            ),
        ],
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    ),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
),
```

(Later, I will remove the blue underline, it's just there to show that it's a 1-liner).

I'm on channel master, v1.2.3-pre.66.

[image: Multiline problem in Flutter]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLength: null,
  maxLines: null,
)
```

All you need is to set `maxLines` to null

Answer (score 3):

Give the property
`maxLines: null`
to the `TextField` widget

```
TextField(
  autofocus: false,
  controller: _text,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLength: null,
  maxLines: null,
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set maxLines as null:

```
TextField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  maxLines: null,
)
```

If the maxLines property is null, there is no limit to the number of lines, and the wrap is enabled.

And you can set min line also by adding

```
minLines: 2    //Number of lines(int), you can replace with your number as per your need
```